# Firestore RecyclerView - Variable null

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

When I save the value that it retrieves from firestore when exiting the function, this value is null.

```
 @Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewDonationHolder holder, int position, @NonNull DonationsClass model) {
    beneficiaryUID = model.getBeneficiaryUid();


    DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("beneficiaries").document(beneficiaryUID);
    docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                if (document.exists()) {
                    beneficiaryFirstName = document.getString("firstName");
                    beneficiaryLastName = document.getString("lastName");
              
                    Log.e("fullName", fullNameBeneficiary);

                } else {
                }
            } else {
            }
                  fullNameBeneficiary = beneficiaryFirstName + " - " + beneficiaryLastName;
        }
    });


    holder.txtFullname.setText(fullNameBeneficiary);
    holder.txtDate.setText(model.getDate());
    holder.txtType.setText(model.getType());
    holder.txtQuantity.setText(model.getQuantity());
    holder.txtDescription.setText(model.getDescription());

}
```

When holder.txtFullname.setText(fullNameBeneficiary) in interface is empty

Comment: There is no way you can do that. Firebase API is asynchronous. So please check the duplicate to see how can you solve this using a callback. You might also be interested in reading this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-cloud-firestore-using-get-bf03b6ee4953).

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to read the article

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like this -

```
DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("beneficiaries").document(beneficiaryUID);
docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
            if (document.exists()) {
                beneficiaryFirstName = document.getString("firstName");
                beneficiaryLastName = document.getString("lastName");
                fullNameBeneficiary = beneficiaryFirstName + " - " + beneficiaryLastName;
                Log.e("fullName", fullNameBeneficiary);
            } 
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried that but not found, the LOG is not seen. Does not go through the function apparently.